# Django-allauth send emails in English when language is set to es-ES

Tags: django, django-allauth

i am using django-allauth and since a big update in my dependencies for some reason all the emails are being sent in English and one it is mixed, a sentence it is in Spanish and the rest in English, even when LANGUAGE_CODE it is defined with my lang (es-ES, i tried only "es" too) at my project settings file.

The settings (base.py):

```
########## GENERAL CONFIGURATION
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Argentina/Cordoba'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-ES'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
########## END GENERAL CONFIGURATION

########## SOCIALACCOUNT CONFIGURATION
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{'facebook':
   {'SCOPE': ['email',],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
    'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
    'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'es-ES',
    'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True}}

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 5
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 6
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'algo.forms.SignupForm'
########## END SOCIALACCOUNT CONFIGURATION
```

I am using django 1.10.2 and allauth 0.27.0, i have uninstalled allauth and re-installed but the problem it is still there.

What can be the issue? Thanks a lot!